# Why is the stack lower than the text in memory?

Tags: windows, memory-management, process, stack, windbg

I'm using Windbg to study about process memory and can't help but notice something people just accept. When you print out the registers:

```
eax=00000000 ebx=008b6f00 ecx=01010101 edx=ffffffff esi=00000000 edi=00465000
eip=77f9d022 esp=05cffc48 ebp=05cffc54 iopl=0         nv up ei ng nz na po nc
cs=001b  ss=0023  ds=0023  es=0023  fs=0038  gs=0000             efl=00000286
```

Notice that ESP and EBP has value lower than EIP, which mean the stack is somewhere lower nthan the text section of the process(!?). Why is this? As far as I know(I have also done the same thing in Linux with gdb), stack is supposed to be in high memory and text in low - just like in many books say.

Is there something that I'm not aware of ?

Comment: The way the memory is laid out is determined by the OS and CPU. The CPU determines which way the stack grows and it is up to the OS where it decides to place the segments. It really could be anywhere but the direction the stack grows is a heavy influence. They put it wherever it makes sense (and in some cases, whatever is more secure).

Comment: The stack still grows downward, and I don't think putting stack lower than text makes sense at all, that's why I'm asking. Can you be more specific as to why putting the stack lower is better than using the memory layout that is in theory?

Comment: Is it question about windows memory management?

Comment: @sergmat: Yes, it pretty much is. I'm expecting stack to be somewhere high (like about `0xbfffxxxx`) and text to be low, so I consider the above strange.

Comment: Thread stack may be located at any address range within user mode virtual address space. [VMMap](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/dd535533.aspx) shows a breakdown of a process's committed virtual memory types as well as the amount of physical memory (working set) assigned by the operating system to those types.

Comment: @linuxuser27, well, I think that point Jeff makes is (at least partially) correct, since when you pop or push something, the x86 instruction increase or decrease ESP respectively, indicating that in x86, stack meant to grow downward.

Comment: What books say that stack is supposed to be in high memory and text low? The only time I've heard anything like that was from MS-DOS where the stack would typically be toward the end of the memory space and the heap at the low end (just after the program/text space) so they would each grow toward the middle. But MS-DOS was a system with a more constrained address space and no virtual memory, so there would be little reason to think that the same techniques would need to be used in modern Windows systems. Especially when you consider that most Win32 programs have more than one stack.

Comment: @MichaelBurr Well, I can't seem to recall one, but if you do a quick "Process Memory Layout" on Google pretty much everywhere will show you the layout that I implied. If you do this on Linux, you will notice that it sticks pretty well with the 'theoretical' layout, despite Linux being a full multitasking with virtual memory implementation. I guess the multiple stack thing is the reason here then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> stack is supposed to be in high memory and text in low

This is a misconception. It is entirely up to the operating system to choose how to lay things out in the process's virtual memory.

In particular, it is worth noting that:

- There isn't a single code segment: the executable and the DLLs can be loaded at address ranges that are not adjacent.
- There isn't a single process stack: each thread has its own separate stack. Again, there is no reason to expect these to be next to each other in memory.

Furthermore, it is considered good security practice to randomize the location of things in memory. See [Address space layout randomization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization).

Comment: Makes sense. But I still not really get why they have to put it all over the place like that. Guess it has something to do with the separate stack thread in the same virtual memory space. So the verdict here is that you cannot expect a clear layout in Window process memory, am I correct?

Comment: @PhamTrungNghia: One reason is http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization

Answer (score 4):

[Thread](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681917(v=vs.85).aspx) stack may be located at any address range within user mode [virtual address space](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/hh439648(v=vs.85).aspx). [VMMap](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/dd535533.aspx) shows a breakdown of a process's committed virtual memory types.
[image]

Comment: @NPE answer was a little bit clearer for me, but thanks for sharing a useful tool.